# Any way to save some data directly in the session in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there any way to save any data in session of Google Earth Engine App user?

- `localStorage` doesn't work
- `cookies` don't work

Any way to save user settings (in json format or whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can save (and decode later) a small amount of data in the URL via `ui.url.set()` and `ui.url.get()`.

Comment: oh nice solution, but how persistant it is?

Comment: Well, it's "permanent" as long as you revisit the modified url.  If you go back to the original URL, it won't be there.

Comment: so basically useless as save (i mean that someone closes application, opens it again and it will load the settings)

Comment: Correct.  Apps are (by design) intended to be anonymous.

Comment: too bad, because it would be useful to be able to at least save some app settings previously selected... now I have to show `prompt()` to allow user to copy paste the settings - not the best solution